# Python multiprocessing - apply_async not working

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am trying to parallelize a code with a ThreadPool. I am currently working on windows. Basically, the behavior that I am getting is that when I call apply_async nothing happens. My program just print START and END.

Below there is an example:

```
import glob
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 


def ppp(window,day):
    print(window,day)


#%% Reading datasets
print('START')
tree = pd.read_csv('datan\\days.csv')
days = list(tree.columns)
windows = [2000]
processes_args = list(itertools.product(windows, days))


pool = ThreadPool(8) 
results = pool.apply_async(ppp, processes_args)
pool.close() 
pool.join() 
print('END')
```

There are many questions on stack that suggest calling other methods, like imap_unordered, map, apply. However, none of them solve the problem.

Edit:

```
results.get()
```

returns an error about the number of parameters:

```
TypeError: ppp() takes 2 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

However, the documentation states that I can use a list of tuples for passing parameters, otherwise how can I pass them?

Edit2:

`processes_args` look likes the output below before calling apply_async:

```
[(2000, '0808'),
 (2000, '0810'),
 (2000, '0812'),
 (2000, '0813'),
 (2000, '0814'),
 (2000, '0817'),
 (2000, '0818'),
 (2000, '0827'),
 (2000, '0828'),
 (2000, '0829')]
```

Comment: You want to inspect the `AsyncResult` outcome to get any error visible. Just call `results.get()`.

Comment: I edited the question, thank you. @noxdafox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positional parameters in `Pool.apply` and `Pool.apply_async` are expanded using the [* unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

According to `processed_args` content, your `ppp` function would receive 10 tuples when scheduled via `apply_async`.

If you want to process an iterable, I'd recommend you to use `Pool.map` or `Pool.map_async`. The `map` functions do not expand the arguments within the iterable. You need to take care of it yourself.

```
def ppp(element):
    window, day = element
    print(window, day)

pool.map(ppp, processed_args)
```

If you want to keep the `ppp` function as is, you can use [`Pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) which applies argument expansion on the iterator content.

Comment: Good point, I am nowadays mostly using `concurrent.futures` or [`pebble`](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/). I forgot about `multiprocessing.Pool` methods. Will update the answer.